# Difference between two If expressions?

Tags: c, if-statement

What is the difference between the following:-

```
  if(source[i] != ' ' && source[i+1] != ' ')        //1
```

and

```
  if(!( source[i] == ' ' && source[i+1] == ' '))     //2
```

Comment: For one thing, the number in the comments is different.

Comment: Think what would happen if `source[i]` is a space but `source[i+1]` is not one....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) should answer your question.

> "not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"

So

```
if(!(source[i]==' '&&source[i+1]==' '))
```

Is like writing

```
if(source[i]!=' ' || source[i+1]!=' ')
```

So.. There is a difference between the two statements you wrote because:

```
if(source[i]!=' ' || source[i+1]!=' ') //if(!(source[i] == ' ' && source[i+1] == ' '))
```

Is **not** like

```
if(source[i]!=' ' && source[i+1]!=' ')
```

Comment: +1. @Juhana It is *very* relevant. :-)

Comment: @Thrustmaster Yeah, the edit makes it clearer. I doubt just saying "look up De Morgan's law" would help anyone who struggles with basic logic.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!(source[i]==' '&&source[i+1]==' '))
```

equals

```
if(source[i]!=' '||source[i+1]!=' ')
```

that's the difference.